# Ubuntu - weird effect of password change

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a system on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

When new users are forced to change their initial password on first logins, the password change mechanism is working improperly.
Below I show real example how it works now (with my comments on the right) and what weird effect with new password finally is:

```
Password:
You are required to change your password immediately (root enforced)
Changing password for user123.
(current) UNIX password: (old password entered)
Enter new UNIX password:  (new password typed - shorter than 14 characters)
Retype new UNIX password:  (retyping password - shorter than 14 characters)
BAD PASSWORD: The password is shorter than 14 characters
New password: (typing again the same new password as above)
BAD PASSWORD: The password is shorter than 14 characters
New password: (still wrong, typing new 14 characters password)
Retype new password: (retyping new 14 characters password)
Password has been already used. Choose another.

Have exhausted maximum number of retries for service
```

After this, the password status is strange - I can't login my old password (ok) but I can't also login my new 14 characters password (sic!) - instead I can login the that shorter than 14 characters passwords which was said "BAD PASSWORD" during passwd changing process above.

What is going wrong with password change process on my Ubuntu?

Comment: Has anyone modified files such as `/etc/login.defs` or pam files?